# Clojure Intellij Cursive plugin JDK error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, clojure

I have a problem with Intellij Cursive plugin: when I'm trying to run New REPL, I receive Error: No JDK for module 'hello'
[image]
But when I start REPL from Terminal: everting works fine. What should I do? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: The Module SDK is set in File > Project Structure dialog, under Project Settings > Modules. Select the 'hello' module and look in the Dependencies tab, Module SDK selector. If you see <None>, then set it to a valid SDK. What setting do you see there currently?

Comment: yes, It was set to <None>, fixed it, now it works, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad you've fixed it! I've added the resolution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The **Module SDK** setting can seen in the **Project Structure** dialog. If the highlighted setting is `<None>`, set it to a valid SDK:

[image]